# Else Expected Expression

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Why is 'else' calling for an expression in this case?

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{


    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"42403E"];
        cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"42403E"];
    else
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"494744"];
        cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"494744"];

}
```

but it does not when I just use:

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{


    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"42403E"];
    else
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"494744"];

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Put both the if and else blocks in brackets. It should solve your problem.

Comment: My rule of thumb: "always" use braces ({}) for block constructs in C-style languages. (My only exception is for a small expression that throws or returns control, when placed on the same line as the conditional.)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{


    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"42403E"];
        cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"42403E"];
    }
    else{
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"494744"];
        cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"494744"];
    }

}
```

It is better to have code blocks if you have more than one line of code after a conditional statement. It's easier for the compiler to parse the flow then.

Hope this helps

Comment: If it helped you and was an adequate answer, please accept the answer, as this is the StackOverflow practice. Thanks :)